# Set a default HTML title tag in apache

Tags: apache

Is it possible to set a `<title>` tag to output on every page in apache? That way instead of it outputting the file name if the page is missing a `<title>` tag, like this:

[image]

It would default to the same thing on every page, like this:

[image]

However, if the page already has a `<title>` tag, apache would respect that:

[image]

Comment: I dont recommend that, it is part of the presentation so it must be on your html. what server side lang are you using?

Comment: This is primarily for non-HTML/PHP pages (images, etc) that I can't (without a weird workaround) add HTML to.